# Find the transition matrix from $(1+x^2,2x,1)$ to $(1,x,x^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

This is a question with its solution i was wondering if it is correct and if it is or it is not can someone explain what is going on and why do we need $B=P^{-1} A P$

$B$ and $A$ are given along with beta and beta'

[image: Check the question here I can't post pictures yet]

Comment: The answer is obviously incorrect since the matrix you came up with is singular—the last column is zero. See if you can figure out what went wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition matrix can't be singular since,  as is fairly easy to see,  you have two bases.

Looks like the problem occurs in the last column,  where you should have $(1,0,0)^t$.

It turns out that that the way the transition matrix $P$ works is that $B=P^{-1}AP$ will be the matrix $A$ expressed in the new basis.  That's precisely because $P$ takes vectors written in the basis $\beta'$ and gives them back written in terms of $\beta$.  ($P^{-1}$ of course does the reverse.)

Comment: Hi Chris, I don’t see how $B$ is the matrix $A$ expressed in our new basis. I would understand if $B = AP$ but my thoughts are multiplying $AP$ by $P^{-1}$ would just take us back to the original basis ?

Comment: Hi.  Well, what happens is $A$ takes vectors written in the old basis,  operates on them, and gives them back in the old basis.   As I said,  $P^{-1}$ goes in the reverse direction,  so $P^{-1}AP=B$ takes vectors written in the the new basis,  operates,  and gives them back in the new basis.   Try breaking it down into $3$ steps.

Comment: ahh I see now thank you

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was going smoothly until the third equation. 
Why did you write $I(1)=0? 
Check that equation.

$$ 1= 1\cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 $$

So your last vector would be $(1,0,0)^t$ making the matrix ($P$) non-singular. 
It is relevant that $P$ is non-singular as you need to invert it (get $P^{-1}$).